# Comparison of two calculation

Tags: linux, bash

```
#! /bin/bash
a=1
until [ $a = 61 ]
do
    echo Value of a = $a
    a=$ expr $a + 10         #First 
    echo first Value: $a          
    a=`expr $a + 10`        #What is first and Second code's difference
    echo second Value: $a      
done
```

**Output**

```
mrjintophilip@LAPTOP-1D73GN8:~$ ./nnn.sh
Value of a = 1
11
first Value: 1
second Value: 11
Value of a = 11
21
first Value: 11
second Value: 21
Value of a = 21
31
first Value: 21
second Value: 31
Value of a = 31
41
first Value: 31
second Value: 41
Value of a = 41
51
first Value: 41
second Value: 51
Value of a = 51
61
first Value: 51
second Value: 61
```

Tell me this bash script code meaning

Answer (score 0):

```
a=$ expr $a + 10
```

Performs the following steps:

1. Replace `$a` with the value of the variable `a`, so it becomes

```
a=$ expr 1 + 10
```

2. Create a subshell process.
3. In that subshell, set the environment variable `a` to `$`.
4. Execute the `expr 1 + 10` command from the subshell. This prints `11` on standard output.

Since the environment variable is set only in the subshell, it has no effect on the value of `a` in the original shell running the script.

```
a=`expr $a + 10`
```

performs the following steps:

1. Replace `$a` with the value of the variable `a`, so it becomes

```
a=`expr 1 + 10`
```

2. Create a subshell.
3. Execute `expr 1 + 10` in the subshell, capturing its standard output.
4. In the original shell, store this output in the variable `a`.

So the difference is that the first one executes the `expr` command while temporarily setting an environment variable, while the second one saves the output of the `expr` command into a variable.